How can I extract the values of the translation keys of my React application?
How can I specify the source of the translation resources to the i18next parser? I also don't understand how to configure multiple namespaces. According to the docs, neither information is provided.
Unfortunately, the values for the keys that have already been created with the corresponding translations are missing in the output.
How can I specify the source of the resource files and, if necessary, store several namespaces?
e.g. i18next-scanner
ns: ["namespace1", "namespace2"],
resource: {
      loadPath: "../../public/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json", // Where translation files should be loaded from
      savePath: "./new_{{ns}}.{{lng}}.json", // Where translation files should be saved to
    },

i18next-parser config file
// CLI call
// i18next --config i18next-parser.config.cjs

module.exports = {
  contextSeparator: "::",
  createOldCatalogs: false,
  defaultNamespace: "translation",
  defaultValue: "__TRANSLATION_REQUIRED__",
  indentation: 4, // Indentation of the catalog files
  keepRemoved: false,
  keySeparator: ".",
  lexers: {
    js: [{lexer: "JavascriptLexer"}],
    jsx: [{lexer: "JsxLexer"}],
    ts: [{lexer: "JavascriptLexer"}],
    tsx: [{lexer: "JsxLexer"}],
    default: ["JavascriptLexer"],
  },
  locales: ["en", "de", "es", "fr", "nl", "pl", "pt"],
  namespaceSeparator: ",",
  input: ["../../src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}", "../../src/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}"],
  output: "./new/$LOCALE/$NAMESPACE.json",
  pluralSeparator: "_", // Plural separator used in your translation keys
  sort: false,
  skipDefaultValues: false,
  useKeysAsDefaultValue: true,
  verbose: true,
  failOnWarnings: false,
  failOnUpdate: false,
  customValueTemplate: null,
  resetDefaultValueLocale: null,
  i18nextOptions: null,
};

Result of scan
{
    "Deliveries": "__TRANSLATION_REQUIRED__",
    "report": {
        "report_one": "__TRANSLATION_REQUIRED__",
...

